# Is there a python video player compatible with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, pygame, pyinstaller

I've worked on a platforming game using pygame and I want to inevitably convert it into .exe using pyinstaller. I just need to find a movie player compatible with pygame and python 3.6 that can be converted using pyinstaller so that I can play the cutscenes that appear in the game in the same window as the game itself. So far I've tried cv2 (does not support audio), moviepy (not compatible with pyinstaller and audio sync issues), ffpyplayer (plays audio but no video).
I've been researching possible libraries to use for the past couple of weeks but I've found nothing so far and I was wondering if I was missing anything or if there's really no proper video player on python 3.6 right now.

Comment: Maybe, this will help(the link uses cx_Freeze): https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-pygame-executable-cx_freeze/